# Retrieving multiple values from C# to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, webmethod

So I have an `a` tag with an onclick:

```
<a onclick="join(4);">Join</a>
```

Now when the `a` tag is clicked, it calls this code in this order:

JavaScript function:

```
function join(gymID) {
        PageMethods.getGymInformation(gymID);
    }
```

C# method:

```
[WebMethod]
public gymData getGymInformation(string gymID)
{
    gyms gym = new gyms();
    DataTable dt = gym.getNewGymInfo(System.Convert.ToInt32(gymID));
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];

    return new gymData { name = dr["name"].ToString(), strength = dr["strength"].ToString(), speed = dr["speed"].ToString(), defence = dr["defence"].ToString()};
}

public DataTable getNewGymInfo(int gymID)
{
    // This returns a datatable with 1 row
    return gymTableApapter.getNewGymInfo(gymID);
}

[Serializable]
public sealed class gymData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string strength { get; set; }
    public string speed { get; set; }
    public string defence { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the JavaScript join function calls the C# method which then retrieves a DataTable with 1 row, then using a custom data type it populates the strings with data to be returned..

Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the information returned from the C# method to be extracted in the JavaScript join function?

Is their a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add success/error callbacks in your JavaScript code.  It might look something like this:

```
PageMethods.getGymInformation(gymID, onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess (result) {
    // result contains the returned value of the method
}

function onError (result) {
    // result contains information about the error
}
```

Then in the `onSuccess` function you would have the returned value of the server-side method (of type `gymData`) in the `result` variable.  At that point you can do whatever you need to do with it in your client-side code.

If the functions don't have any applicable re-use, you can even just add them in-line:

```
PageMethods.getGymInformation(gymID,
    function (result) {
        // success
    }, function (result) {
        // error
    });
```

Comment: How would I extract it from the result? Would it just be result.name, result.strength and so on?

Comment: @mogorilla: Most likely, unless the framework is wrapping it in an enclosing object or in some other way modifying it.  You can confirm this in the debugger, though.  In your browser's debugger, put a breakpoint in the success callback function.  When stopped on that breakpoint, examine the runtime value of `result`.

Comment: Looking at the console, upon clicking the anchor tag I get an error "PageMethods is not defined" ?

Comment: @mogorilla: That's an entirely different issue.  Have you added `EnablePageMethods="true"` in `ScriptManager`?

Comment: How stupid of me, totally my bad. But I'll get with break pointing the code